# Cancelling MATLAB object construction without exceptions?

Tags: oop, matlab

In a MATLAB class I am writing, if the constructor is given 0 arguments, the user is asked to provide a file using `uigetfile`. If the user cancels the prompt, `uigetfile` returns `0`. In that case it makes no sense to make the object. Is there some way of cancelling the object construction without throwing an exception? If I do an early return I get a malformed object that cannot be used. Here is what the code looks like:

```
classdef MyClass
    methods
        function self = MyClass(filename)
            if nargin == 0
                filename = uigetfile;
                if filename == 0
                    %cancel construction here
                    return; %I still get a MyClass object with self.filename == []
                end
            end   
            self.filename = filename;
        end
    end

    properties
        filename;
    end
end
```

However I am unsure if using `uigetfile` in the constructor is the right thing to do. Maybe it should be the resposibility of another part of my code.

Comment: to program clearly I suggest to remove all this gui stuff if filename is obligatory argument. You can provide assistance for a user by simple assert:  assert(nargin == 1, 'filename must be provided!');

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In modern Matlab objects, I don't think it's possible to get out of the constructor without either returning a constructed object or throwing an error. (In the old style classes, the constructor was actually allowed to return whatever it wanted, including objects or primitives of other types, and oh man could that turn in to a mess.) When a constructor is called, the output argument is already intialized with an object with the default property values, so when you call `return` there, it just skips the rest of initialization and returns the object. If you try to replace out with something besides a MyClass object, that's an error.

Just reorganize the control flow to pull the GUI code out of the constructor, like you're speculating on at the end. Mixing it in to the constructor, especially conditionally, can cause problems. In particular, Matlab expects the zero-arg constructor to always return a scalar object with some sort of default values, because the zero-arg gets called implicitly when filling in elements during array expansion and so on. It's basically used as a prototype.

Comment: Yup.  Just make the constructor REQUIRE a good filename, and put the conditional stuff outside.  If you want to standardize it, you can put it in a static factory method.

Comment: Interesting stuff about how the MATLAB object are constructed. As others have also advised, I ended up removing user interation from the constructor. It also makes my code significantlz simpler